# Python win32COM/pyautogui doesn't show hebrew text

Tags: python, character-encoding, multilingual, win32com, hebrew

I'm working on a project where I need a Win32com package to read all open Excel files and display them with a simple GUI using pyautogui (not necessarily pyautogui, any gui package will do). Any file with a Hebrew name doesn't appear in the list.

```
import tkinter as tk


def get_open_workbooks():
    xl = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    workbooks = xl.Workbooks
    open_workbooks = []
    print(workbooks)
    print(workbooks.Count)

    for i in range(1, workbooks.Count + 1):
        workbook = workbooks.Item(i)
        if workbook.Name:
            open_workbooks.append(workbook.Name)

    return open_workbooks


def create_ui():
    open_workbooks = get_open_workbooks()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Open Excel Workbooks")
    root.geometry("400x300")  # Set window size

    listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
    listbox.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    print(open_workbooks)
    for workbook in open_workbooks:
        listbox.insert(tk.END, workbook)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_ui()
```

^^^ This is the code I'm using

The print statements return only the english filenames (in this example it would log "2" and "[filename1],[filename3]"

[image]

^^^ This is what it shows when i have 3 workbooks (3 files) open 2 have English file names and one has a Hebrew filename

[image]
These are the open excel files

Comment: Why does Books has an `.xlsx` extension, and the other files are without extensions?

Comment: @Rotem I'm not sure, but it wouldn't affect it anyway since one of the english named files doesnt have .xlsx and still shows up

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. When I open 3 `.xlsx` files, two file names in English and one file name in Hebrew, all 3 are displayed. Can you try that? (for testing try using 3 `.xlsx` files without any content).

Comment: Yep, seems the file that didn't show up was in "protected mode" which I guess hid it from win32com and didn't register as an open Excel file. Thanks for the help Rotem 

Answer (score 0):

Excel files sometimes open in "protected view" (learn more [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-protected-view-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653)) which opens suspicious in a read-only mode and win32com doesn't register these files as open excel files as implemented in the code above.